# Coleman-Mandula theorem in mathematical language

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, supersymmetry

Every supersymmetry text starts off mentioning the [Coleman-Mandula theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman%E2%80%93Mandula_theorem). Often it is introduced using rather colloquial terminology. I was wondering if anyone knew a precise mathematical formulation of the theorem.

Comment: For everyone interested, here's a link to the original paper: http://prola.aps.org/abstract/PR/v159/i5/p1251_1

Comment: Weinberg Volume 3 has a derivation of the theorem in the first (or maybe second) chapter.

Comment: Possible answer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3645/

Comment: I find that this paper is particularly accessible and constitutes a nice derivation of the individual elements of the proof. http://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/~busbridge/files/documents/CMtheorem.pdf

Comment: A good source where to find a mathematical version of the Coleman-Manula theorem is pointed out [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/22018/coleman-mandula-theorem-in-mathematical-language?show=23493#a23493)