# Symmetries in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, group-theory, representation-theory

There are very famous [Coleman–Mandula theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman%E2%80%93Mandula_theorem) and [Haag–Łopuszański–Sohnius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haag%E2%80%93%C5%81opusza%C5%84ski%E2%80%93Sohnius_theorem) , see also [this](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Ewalcher/teaching/sose16/geo_phys/ColemanMandula.pdf) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3645/).

It states that "space-time and internal symmetries cannot be combined in any but a trivial way".

But this theorem didn't give any restrictions on internal symmetry group. Which symmetries can be realised in QFT?
What about [Quantum group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_group), [Hopf algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_algebra)? Or maybe more exotic algebras?

**Which internal symmetries one can realise in QFT?**

Comment: If Lie, zero-form symmetries are [reductive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductive_group). Higher-form symmetries are finitely-generated abelian groups. Symmetries of different rank may mix into higher categorical structures, cf. e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04790. So if you have, say, both zero-form and one-form symmetries, these may interact in a way that doesn't close to a group, in the classical sense. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: Also in two dimensions symmetries can be shown to form a fusion category https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02330

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform,  thank you! Yes, your answers are very useful! Really, I wanna to understand, which symmetries can be realised in QFT. If you know some other examples, please, write here!

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə, thank you! If you know some other unusual symmetries in QFT, please, write here.